# Bandwith Raspberry PI 3 USB and Ethernet, need more bandwith on my USB ports

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, gnuradio

I am working on a project to send song from my HACKRF ONE. Actually I can't reduce more the sample_rate of my HACKRF on GNU RADIO.

I know my ethernet port and USB ports share the same bandwith and I wouldlike to know if I disable the ethernet port, do I will win more bandwith on my USB ports or it change nothing ? Did exist another way to win more bandwith?

[FlowGraph Emetteur HACK RF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsKhV.png)

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. As long as you don't send data over the ethernet link, the USB bandwidth usage should be negligible.

The usual problem here is CPU bandwidth, often due to inefficient software design. Start profiling your GNU Radio flow graph! Figure out where time is spent, and optimize!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so ok I can only win more bandwith if my CPU process less data ? I just add too my flowgraph.

Comment: Your flowgraph runs at a totally unnecessarily high sampling rate.

Comment: I can't reduce more the sample rate. I ear nothing if I am less than 1M. I'm using HACK RF ONE.

Comment: Then you've got a different issue. You don't need 1MS/s to transport 176 kHz of bandwidth, simple as that.

Comment: it said "Using a sampling rate of less than 8MHz is not recommended. Partly, this is because the MAX5864 (ADC/DAC chip) isn't specified to operate at less than 8MHz, and therefore, no promises are made by Maxim about how it performs. But more importantly, the baseband filter in the MAX2837 has a minimum bandwidth of 1.75MHz" the wiki : https://github.com/mossmann/hackrf/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks